# Is there any difference between these three ways of declaring methods in JS?

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

Say I have a type called `MyObject` and I want to add the method `myMethod` to it. Is there any difference (logically, but also performance-wise) between the following ways?

**#1**

```
function MyObject() {
    ...
}

MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function() {
   ...
};
```

**#2**

```
function MyObject() {
    this.myMethod = function() {
        ...
    };
    ...
}
```

**#3**

```
function MyObject() {
    this.myMethod = myMethod;
    ...
}

function myMethod() {
    ...
}
```

I wouldn't mind knowing if there's a performance difference - e.g. if way #2 is costly because it defines the function separately every time an object is instantiated - but **I'm mostly concerned with whether the results are equivalent.**

In addition, with method #2, isn't this the same way that a class-level/static method would be defined, so does it have the danger of being called like `MyObject.myMethod();`? If `myMethod` used `this` and it was called on `MyObject` rather than an instance of `MyObject`, I would think this would cause issues. So does the compiler/interpreter check to see whether `this` is present or would it throw an error?

Comment: #1 and #2 are ok, but #3 is not; you're creating an unnecessary global function.

Comment: Right, #3 is different in that regard. I wouldn't use it myself - but some of the code base I'm working with uses it to aid in polymorphism (calling by multiple types that all share the same function). Other than that though, it's equivalent?

Comment: Of course they are different, when prototyping you're creating methods that inherit when a new instance is instantiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1**: This is the preferred way to write "class-level" methods. This saves on memory (as you'll see in #2) and JS engines can know that each instance will have this method and optimize around that.

**#2**: You're right, this one is more costly because it creates a new function for each instance. The difference here is that you can include private variables generated in the constructor. For example:

```
function MyObject() {
    var name = 'Me';
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };
}
```

Only things created in the constructor will have access to `name`.

**#3**: This approach is largely the same as #1 but I imagine that JavaScript engines are not written to optimize for this case (but this might not be true and may change, JS engines are constantly evolving). This also creates a global function (assuming you're not using a module system) which can create major issues later.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, you did a good job showing the pros and cons of each one.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: You can call my method without instantiating MyObject:

```
MyObject.prototype.myMethod();
```

Options 2: You must instantiate the MyObject to be able to access myMethod.

This will fail:

```
MyObject2.myMethod();
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This will not:

```
var myObject = new MyObject2();
myObject.myMethod();
```

Check out the code pen: http://codepen.io/sessa/pen/tfqln

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to prevent `myMethod` - as defined in option #1 - from being called from a non-instance? Or is option #2/3 (using a `this` in the constructor) the only way to prevent that?

Comment: Once you set a method to the objects prototype, it is callable without instantiation.  So, yes, #2 is a way of forcing object instantiation before invoking a method.